# python - Getting Pip to use MinGW32 on Windows?

Tags: python, pip, mingw32

This has been asked and answered a few times, but as you'll see none of the previous answers work for me -- I feel like something had changed to make all the old answers outdated. Or at the very least, I'm in some kind of edge case:

On a Windows 7 box, I've installed MinGW32 and Python 2.7 (32 bit version) (I've also tried this with Python 2.6 and got the same results).

- Path environment variable is set correctly.
- I've edited `cygwincompiler.py` to remove refrences to `-mno-cygwin`. And I've put the correct `distutils.cfg` file into `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils`.
- To be clear: `distutils.cfg` contains `[build] compiler=mingw32` on two lines.
- I've also (just to be safe) put `pydistutils.cfg` in my `%HOME%` directory. And put `setup.cfg` in my current directory when running `pip`. They have same content as `distutils.cfg`.

I know this is all working because `pip install cython` and `pip install pycrypto` both compile successfully.

However, mysteriously, some packages still give me the `unable to find vcvarsall.bat` error. Two examples are: pyproj and numpy.

It's as if sometimes `pip` knows to use the MinGW compiler and sometimes it doesn't?

Moreover, if I use the MSYS shell that comes with MinGW then magically `pip install numpy` succeeds. But `pip install pyproj` still fails with an `unable to find vcvarsall.bat`.

I've tried this out on several machines all with the exact same results.

Anybody have any idea what's going on here? Why would `pip` know to use mingw32 to compile some c modules and not others? Also, why does `pip install numpy` work inside the MSYS shell but not inside the cmd shell?

BONUS: Many, many older answers suggest installing Visual Studio 2008 as a way of solving a `vcvarsall.bat` error. But as of this past May, microsoft is no longer distributing this software. Does anyone know of a place where one can still download VS2008? I ask because it's possible that being able to use `vcvarsall.bat` instead of MinGW would solve this problem.

Comment: +1 I do have the exact same problem: sometimes pip is able to find mingw, sometimes he cannot.

Comment: You don't need all of VS2008, you just need the windows SDK, which is still available for download.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138 (link will probably not age well)

Answer (score 1):

visual studio express 2008 http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/5/8B5804AD-4990-40D0-A6AA-CE894CBBB3DC/VS2008ExpressENUX1397868.iso

Or if you're a student, you can still get Visual Studio 2008 through dreamspark https://www.dreamspark.com/

IMHO I'd recommend using Visual Studio 2008 because the official distributions of Python are all compiled with Visual Studio and is the "official" windows compiler for cpython. http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-April/573606.html

FYI Python 33 is compiled with Visual Studio 2010.

Finally, you could just install packages from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: That's not an answer to the question. ¬_¬

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this issue for a while, and found that sometimes pip seems to ignore `MSYS_HOME` and can't find `pydistutils.cfg`, in which case the only recourse seems to be manually copying the `pydistutils.cfg` into your virtualenv right before running `pip install`.

It sure would be great if someone could definitively figure out why it sometimes finds this file and sometimes does not. Environment variables seem excessively finicky in MinGW.